# altering a serializable class by adding static methods, java

Tags: java, serializable

My serializable class is not getting read in with objectinputstream after adding static methods to the class, is this expected behavior? Where in the javadoc does it state adding static methods to a serializable class creates incompatibility?

Comment: It's impossible to really diagnose your problem without more information.  Please post some code, and describe the issue a bit more.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.io.InvalidClassException:  local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 2421933566308851961, local class serialVersionUID = 6969314805631849195, all i did was add static methods, adding in the old serialversion uid fixed the problem

Comment: Thanks.  This of course means that Jon Skeet solved your problem, which is never a surprise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Java Object Serialization Specification, section [4.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/class.html#4100):

> The stream-unique identifier is a 64-bit hash of the class name, interface class names, methods, and fields.
>
> ...
>
> For each non-private method sorted by method name and signature:
>
> - The name of the method.
> - The modifiers of the method written as a 32-bit integer.
> - The descriptor of the method.

No, I can't work out how it could actually break compatibility of serialized state either, but this is why it's *either* worth avoiding the default Java binary serialization (e.g. for [Protocol Buffers](http://protobuf.googlecode.com)) *or* always declaring a `serialVersionUid` yourself.